# Numenera, The Basics

Tags: new-players, numenera

I've been interested in Numenera for a bit after watching some YouTube videos and I want to know where I can basically find player guides etc. So that I could join a group.

Comment: Are you wanting to know where to find the *rulebooks*, or are you wanting to know where to find "tutorial" or "FAQ" types of pages?

Answer (score 3):

You can buy PDFs of the rules from [RPGNow](http://www.rpgnow.com/browse.php?manufacturers_id=4952). If you're looking to join a group as a player, the [Player's Guide](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/114852/Numenera-Players-Guide?manufacturers_id=4952) should be all you need.